# Setting up paypal sandbox and testing with my website

Tags: testing, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've been using my PayPal business account for years, processing orders from my website.  I'm getting busy enough now that I want to enable and test some advanced features through my scripts.

For example, I want to place a fictitious order so that I can see that the redirects are working, and I can grab transaction information and log it.  What I have been doing for the time being is placing an order on my website, processing it, and then refunding the order.   This is really tedious and silly.

But I can't seem to find through the documentation a very simple way to do this.  All I want to do is process a fictitious order so I can test the environment.

Is there an easy, well documented process for doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the link below about PayPal Sandbox. You can test your payment process on Sandbox environment.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_overview/

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/

Comment: I did this.  I have a business sandbox email account called "customerservice-facilitator@customdevtech.com"    In my form that calls the PayPal checkout, I now have it as "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/websrc".    When I click "checkout" it takes me to PayPal, but I notice in the URL it doesn't have the word "sandbox" in the URL.  Should it?   I tried to "pay" with my facilitator account, but it didn't work.   Not sure what I am doing wrong.